# IOError in python for meanwhile slide a query result

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop, scripting, psycopg2

I've got an issue with this part of python script. When I run it, it throws this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

in a RANDOM ELEMENT of `dbCur` (result of query).

Here is my code:

```
dbCur.execute("SELECT parent_name FROM crowd.cwd_membership WHERE child_name = \'"+source+"\'")
for group in dbCur:
    code = 999

    # Check sul nome visualizzato
    if ('-' in group):
        print "Aggiungo il gruppo: ", group[0], " all' utente di destinazione..."
        code = giveGroup(jira,target,group[0])
    if (code != 400 or code != 404):
        # Se andata a buon fine 
        print " ...Gruppo aggiunto con successo \n"
    if (code == 400 or code == 404):
        # Se utente o gruppo non trovati, manda in review manuale
        requireReview = True
    if (code==999):
        # Se il nome non è corretto O non esiste, non fa partire la giveGroup
        print "...Nome gruppo non valido, "
        autogrant_crowd_clog.logger.info("Errore nel nome del gruppo: "+group[0]+ " l'inserimento è stato saltato.")
```

Comment: Your question can be improved by adding more information; like, what are you trying to achieve. Take a look at the [How to ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I' ve to applicate the function "giveGroup" for each row of dbCur, the problem is that meanwhile the for cycle is working , sometimes i get that IO Error, don't know why, the result's row is consistent.